# TexStudio with LuaLatex and latexmk - is this possible?

Tags: luatex, texstudio, biber, latexmk

After learning about `latexmk` I really would love to use it within TexStudio. For bibliography, I'm also using `biber`.

- Is this possible?
- It would be very nice, if perhaps somebody could give
  me a hint about how to configure this, please? (I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and TexLive)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible and also quite easy.:

- Go to **Configurate TexStudio** and then choose **Commands**, scroll down and insert in **latexmk** `latexmk -lualatex -silent -latexoption="-synctex=1" %`
- Be carefull with scrolling it may change what you have entered without noticing it (this was my mistake all the time)

[image: Example configuration]

- If using the option `-lualatex` there is no need for `-pdf`
- `-synctex=1` flag allows you to jump between the pdf-viewer and the editor by simple clicking on the desired part.
- Important notice: `Latexmk: Run number X of rule 'pdflatex'` doesn't mean you are using pdflatex, because the *'pdflatex'* is handled as placeholder. It is using lualatex (when you use the `-lualatex` Option) (See **Note 2** in the [offical manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf))

Answer (score -1):

```
latexmk.exe -lualatex -shell-escape -silent -synctex=1 %
```

This command has been tested on Windows operative system.

Comment: Can you please explain, what exactly has to be changed in TeXStudio to use this single line of whatever? And please also explain, why always using `-shell-escape` should be done instead of using the TimK's answer without this option? Currently, I would tend to see this not as a complete answer but maybe as a comment, but don't know, whether it should be a comment to the existing answer or to the question. And IMHO currently it tend to say: Use `-shell-escape` only for known documents. This option is not really harmless if used carelessly.

Comment: Go to Configurate TexStudio and then choose Commands, scroll down and insert in latexmk