# arara/latexmk: How to pass more options of latexmk engine to arara?

Tags: luatex, latexmk, arara

In the [manual of arara](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/support/arara/doc/arara-manual.pdf), there are only two options for `latexmk`: `clean` and `engine`.

However, as similarly done before in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480997/2288) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351728/2288), I need to figure out to pass more options of the engine (e.g. `lualatex`) such as `synctex`, `shell-escape`, and `interactionmode=nonstop` (I am not sure if the last option makes sense with `latexmk` or not).

Furthermore, is it possible to pass the options of `latexmk` itself to arara such as `-silent`?

Comment: Sorry, I counted four options for `latexmk`. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda It is my bad :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's actually another option named `options` which takes a list of raw command line options and appends it to the actual script call. So you could call `latexmk`like this:

```
% arara: latexmk: { options: [ '-silent' ] }
```

For each extra option, enclose it as a list element, such as

```
% arara: latexmk: { options: [ 'opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3' ] }
```

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, you show here how to add options of `latexmk` but what about the engine itself? For example, I need something like `% !arara: latexmk: { engine : lualatex, engine options = {synctex = true, shell = true , interaction = nonstopmode} }` .

Comment: Do you mean it can be done by `% arara: latexmk: { options: [ '-silent','-lualatex' , '-silent', '-synctex=1', '-interaction=nonstopmode' ] }`?

Comment: @Diaa If latexmk can pass this then use the same strategy with arara. Otherwise make a feature request for latexmk.

Comment: @Diaa Have you tried the `-latexoption` option to latexmk (from its documentation)?

Comment: @TeXnician I searched for `latexoption` in the latexmk manual PDF but I didn't find it.

Comment: @Diaa Try `latexmk --help`.

Comment: Almost all of the options accepted by the TeX engines are also accepted by latexmk.  Run `latexmk -showextraoptions` to see the possibilities.  So `-latexoption` is not normally needed, unless you've got some special exotic case.