# Automating the Build and View (F5)

Tags: texstudio, automation

Is there a way to automate the Build and View (F5) function such that it knows which command to use amongst `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xetex` and `lualatex`? For example, if I load the `fontspec`, I want my Texstudio to automatically call the `xetex` command when I press F5 (Build and View). Is there any way to configure my Texstudio to behave in such a way?

Comment: You can configure tesxtudio to use `latexmk`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351728/29873

Comment: The solution you have cited is using lualatex as the option and is not yet solving my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. You want some magic that determines what you are doing in the document. For that, I have, indeed, no solution. But then again, lualatex can compile almost every document that be compiled with either pdflatex or xelatex, so it might work after all

Comment: Yes of course, I want some configuration that determines what command to use amongst  `pdflatex`, `lualatex`, `xetex`etc

Comment: Perhaps "magic comments" could be of use: https://www.texdev.net/2011/03/24/texworks-magic-comments/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78101/when-and-why-should-i-use-tex-ts-program-and-tex-encoding